# How to create a new column that increments within a subgroup of a group in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a problem where I need to group the data by two groups, and attach a column that sort of counts the subgroup.

Example dataframe looks like this:

```
colA colB
 1     a 
 1     a  
 1     c  
 1     c  
 1     f  
 1     z 
 1     z  
 1     z  
 2     a  
 2     b  
 2     b
 2     b
 3     c  
 3     d  
 3     k  
 3     k 
 3     m  
 3     m  
 3     m
```

Expected output after attaching the new column is as follows:

```
colA colB colC
 1     a    1
 1     a    1
 1     c    2
 1     c    2
 1     f    3
 1     z    4
 1     z    4
 1     z    4
 2     a    1
 2     b    2
 2     b    2
 2     b    2
 3     c    1  
 3     d    2 
 3     k    3    
 3     k    3 
 3     m    4
 3     m    4
 3     m    4
```

I tried the following but I cannot get this trivial looking problem solved:

Solution 1 I tried that does not give what I am looking for:

```
df['ONES']=1
df['colC']=df.groupby(['colA','colB'])['ONES'].cumcount()+1
df.drop(columns='ONES', inplace=True)
```

I also played with transform, and cumsum functions, and apply, but I cannot seem to solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: minor error on dataframes.

Edit 2: For simplicity purposes, I showed similar values for column B, but the problem is within a larger group (indicated by colA), colB may be different and therefore, it needs to be grouped by both at the same time.

Edit 3: Updated dataframes to emphasize what I meant by my second edit. Hope this makes it more clear and reproduceable.

Comment: Yes, I corrected it, should be similar now.

Comment: Could you explain how `colA` is relevant in assigning a value to `colC`? With the current example, it's not relevant at all.

Comment: Yes, I did not think it would be irrelevant with the way I created the example. I tried to update it. Hope it is clear now to explain how the larger group (colA) is relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `groupby` + `ngroup`:

```
df['colC'] = df.groupby('colA').apply(lambda x: x.groupby('colB').ngroup()+1).droplevel(0)
```

Output:

```
    colA colB  colC
0      1    a     1
1      1    a     1
2      1    c     2
3      1    c     2
4      1    f     3
5      1    z     4
6      1    z     4
7      1    z     4
8      2    a     1
9      2    b     2
10     2    b     2
11     2    b     2
12     3    c     1
13     3    d     2
14     3    k     3
15     3    k     3
16     3    m     4
17     3    m     4
18     3    m     4
```

Comment: Just with your hint of ngroup, I tried it a similar way and it worked. Thanks a lot. Such trivial problem I kept banging my wall against!

Comment: @kukushkin I'm still not convinced of the difference. Maybe it makes a difference in your data but with the new sample, the current code produces the same output as the previous code.

Comment: It does make a difference when it is timestamp data. I need to think a little bit further for  an example or maybe create a synthetic simulated data next time I post something that is pretty ambiguous when treated trivially like I did!

Answer (score 0):

Categorically, factorize

```
df['colC'] =df['colB'].astype('category').cat.codes+1



 colA colB  colC
0      1    a     1
1      1    a     1
2      1    b     2
3      1    b     2
4      1    c     3
5      1    d     4
6      1    d     4
7      1    d     4
8      2    a     1
9      2    b     2
10     2    b     2
11     2    b     2
12     3    a     1
13     3    b     2
14     3    c     3
15     3    c     3
16     3    d     4
17     3    d     4
18     3    d     4
```